# Same code works different on different environments (there is no Content-length at response header)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csv, content-length

I am working on an old ASP.NET project. A csv file is downloaded via the application. After a call to another service at the back, the csv file can be prepared and downloaded.
While this feature works smoothly in the development environment, the csv files downloaded in the production environment are incomplete.
Working codes are the same. I add working code and responses. any idea would be a great help. Thanks

```
string url = "https://graph.someservice.net/service.php";

    //Create a WebRequest to get the file
    HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    //Create a response for this request
    HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

    using (Stream stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream())
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
            ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
        } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);

        // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
        var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        resp.ContentType = "text/csv";
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Request.QueryString["serviceName"] + ".csv\"");
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

        // Verify that the client is connected.
        if (resp.IsClientConnected)
        {
            // write data out to the response's output stream
            resp.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);

            resp.End();

        }
    }
```

prod response :

```
cache-control: private
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"
content-type: text/csv
date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 19:05:50 GMT
server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
status: 200
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
```

dev response :

```
cache-control: private
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"
content-length: 42229
content-type: text/csv
date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 19:06:13 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
status: 200
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to debug your code for you when you haven't even done the simplest thing: ensure your dev environment is using the same version of nginx as prod.

Comment: believe me I debugged the code least 30 times.there is no any problem on my local machine also. thanks for nginx suggestion.

Comment: However, both versions of `nginx` are outdated. Afaik, 1.18.0 is the latest stable now.

Comment: @aepot thanks I will update nginx on both machine then test it again...